# Gluon Mobile direct connection to mysql server

Tags: mysql, javafx-8, gluon-mobile

Is it possible to connect Gluon Mobile (Javafx) to mysql server without any webservice? If yes, any sample code to help?

Comment: Try JDBC connection

Comment: What have you tried and what exactly doesn't work for you? Read more about what types of question you should [avoid asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and how to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  when you ask on SO.